# ReactJS with Django - real usage

Tags: reactjs, django

I was messing around a bit with React and I quite like it. It's much more verbose than Angular (ng-repeat with | filter is priceless) but ok.

The thing, that is bugging me, is how I'm supposed to use React with Django templates. Should I put all the javascript into templates along with the "HTML" markup.

Implementing Angular was quite seamless. I just put some attributes into template/django form class and then wrote javascript in a separated file. Include that file and it's done.

How to "use" react? What is the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right from the horse's mouth: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/08/19/use-react-and-jsx-in-python-applications.html

Comment: Thankks, but I still don't get how should I separate my app code.

Comment: we use django with react on the frontend. We just use django for our rest api and an all react frontend.

Comment: Well, that's the only way I can imagine right now

Answer (score 84, accepted):

*Since you want to use React along with Django templates, I assume the React code will only affect specific parts of your page. The following explanations are written based on that assumption.*

First of all, you don't have to put all the JS code in the template — in fact, that would be a mess.

You can create a separate JS-based build process [using Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) ([check out this howto](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto)). That enhances your client-side code's capabilities, allowing you to use CommonJS modules in the browser, which you can directly pull from npm, including [React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react).

Webpack in turn will generate a bundle (or multiple bundles, depending on the nature of your application and the Webpack configuration) which you'll need to include in your Django templates via `<script>` tags as usual.

Now you need to make the `React.render()` call to render your React application somewhere in the existing page layout. You'll need to use an empty HTML element with a specific id/class name as a mount point for the application.

But here comes the caveat: you cannot access CommonJS modules directly from the browser or Django templates. So either you,

- expose `React` and your app to the `window` object, or
- create a module with glue code to handle app initialization and expose that method to the `window` object.

In any of the cases you will need to call the initialization code directly from the templates (check out [an example of glue code](https://github.com/translate/pootle/blob/1700d26ce2977da58a48a0a79454343b6829563c/pootle/static/js/admin/app.js#L27-L46), and the [call to app initialization](https://github.com/translate/pootle/blob/1700d26ce2977da58a48a0a79454343b6829563c/pootle/templates/admin/projects.html#L12-L20)).

This initialization step also allows you to pass variables available in Django templates to the JS code.

The final Django template will look something like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'path/to/app.bundle.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Initialization glue code
  window.MyApp.init({el: '.app-mountpoint'});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Your template contents -->

<!-- The mount point of your app -->
<div class="app-mountpoint" />
{% endblock %}
```

And the glue code:

```
var React = require('react');

var MyAppComponent = require('MyAppComponent');


window.MyApp = {

  init: function (opts) {
    var mountPoint = document.querySelector(opts.el);

    React.render(<MyAppComponent />, mountPoint);
  }

};
```

I know all of this might sound overwhelming at the beginning (even more compared to the few steps you had with Angular), but believe me it pays off in the long run.

So summarizing:

1. Write React code in separate JS files
2. Use Webpack (leveraging CommonJS modules) to bundle your React code
3. Include the bundle in your Django templates
4. Render the React code using glue code in Django templates

Comment: so basically the story when django renders components like form or grid ends with React?

Comment: Django templates know nothing about the components you render using React, and the same applies the other way round. So for instance React won't be able to understand a form you render via `{{ form.as_p }}`, even if you add attributes in the fields as you would in Angular. In this context a Django form will only serve you to validate the data server side.

Comment: So how zackify wrote, in this case Django is pure backend that serves data . Whole template and render logic is useless because all the HTML is in JS (React components). Right?

Comment: It's up to you, but it's not a requirement to have 100% React code for your Django app. It mostly depends on what UI and interactions you want to build on the client-side. As displayed above, it's possible to have both Django templates and React code side-by-side.

Comment: @julen: I was trying to follow your instruction but I got error on the initialization glue code: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined`. Any clue what's going on?

Comment: That sounds like the reference to the global object is not correct (`window.MyApp` or similar); make sure you typed it correctly. Also your script file which defines the glue code needs to be included before calling it.

Comment: You no longer have to bind anything to the `window` object to mount React. You can simply use `ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.querySelector('.app-mountpoint'))` if your bundle file is included in the template.

Comment: Why do you need the window exposure or glue code? All you should need to do is make a div to house the React components, and call your JS page entry point with a script tag. Point reactDOM.render func to your div.

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute because `ReactDOM` is not available in the JS context where the Django-generated HTML page is rendered. You could alternatively add `ReactDOM` to `window` or add `ReactDOM` via a script tag and avoid any glue code, which would then allow you to use `ReactDOM.render` right away. Note however the answer is just one way to achieve a goal, and there is no one and only way to get there.

Comment: @julen Thanks - You explained why React's official tutorial has script tags, and why I was surprised at the glue part of the post.

Answer (score 9):

What if you'd consider the frontend and the backend as two different, independent entities? I mean the following:

1. Django should only be an API and respond with json data
2. [The frontend should be only static files served by nginx](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/.nginx.conf)
3. You may have to deal with [CORS](https://www.google.com/search?q=CORS&oq=CORS&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.971j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in order to allow communication between the two. One option would be to allow preflight requests from your frontend and the other option would be to set up an nginx proxy. This is a separate issue and you should search for it if you need more details.

I think this architecture allows you to keep things separated and not deal with their integration. Things are already too complicated on the frontend/React ecosystem so I think simplicity of config has to be taken into account.

I would also be interested to find out how a deployment process would look for this architecture (what tools to use?), so please add comments if you have suggestions and I'll update the response accordingly to supply useful info for future readers.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented something similar to what you are asking. My front end is entirely on reactjs which is compiled using webpack and my templates are created in django.

So I do following:-

1. Use react-router and react to create .jsx/.js code.
2. Compile using webpack.
3. Use [django-webpack](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader)

So django-webpack works really nice and helps you isolated you compilation outside of django to get thinks working in a nice and scalable way.

Comment: what do you mean by "frontend is entirely on reactjs" but "templates are created in Django"? If the frontend is entirely on reactjs, are you using Django templates at all?
(I have some forms rendered by Django and now trying to use DRF to move the rendering to React. Trying to figure things out with the limited information/docs available online - hence asking. Thanks)

Comment: I had few templates in django when I started my project, but then slowly I moved entire front end to react with Django Rest as backend. Now I use templates only for server side rendering for SEO purposes . If u need any help regarding migrations would love to help :)

Comment: Thanks - would you know of any good examples that demonstrate rendering Django forms through DRF and React? I have been spending significant time figuring this out but a real example would really help validate my understanding. There are some DRF+React examples out there but I am specifically looking for one that sends form data through DRF and React in turn renders a form with the data.

Comment: I didnt try to use django forms with react, because i found redux form to be really amazing and scalable for my project. I would strongly suggest bring in redux in picture and move your entire front end to react-redux

Comment: Sure, I may try Redux a little later. Just trying to get basic things in place right now. Have already learnt a ton of new tools to use React :) But I get your point. If you know of any good online examples of rendering Django forms through React, that would also help for now.

Comment: Django templates do not help with SSR. You need Node for that. There is really no advantage of using Django templates at all. You can build a completely isolated ReactJS frontend and just populate data through REST APIs to/from DRF.

Comment: yup done that .. i was using that while moving django project to react. Now its react/redux/webpack front end with django-rest handling the apis