# Map urls into react components

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

Hi guys im implementing react in my cms app served by django framework, i have an idea, but im not sure how to implement it, i have a generic view with a sidebar, this sidebar redirect to url's that shows diferent information about users, i have a generic django template and some templates that inherit from this one, each one from a django view url, every template have a form that manages the information, i first thnik doing a single django-react template and have a component, for each other template, but some important things are defined by the view, how can i asign each djangoview to a react component?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610372/reactjs-with-django-real-usage

Comment: I already read that, but i want that react encapsulates all my cms in one url, and having the view url's like components in react.